# Permission denied error while building IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I’ve suddenly come across an issue building my app on IOS with XCode and I can’t figure out what has changed to cause the issue.

Xcode version is 12.2, iOS deployment target is 11.0

I'm building an app with Ionic (Capacitor).

I was previously able to build the App with no issues however now when I try and build it fails with this error:

```
error: fopen(/Users/#{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-exhubkdpgkxayrdhquijdacqgwye/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/Frameworks/Cordova.framework/Cordova, rb): Permission denied (13) (in target 'App' from project 'App')
```

I’ve tried to chmod the permissions in the Cordova.framework directory but that hasn’t done anything.

I've removed the DerivedData and cleaned the project.

I've removed the IOS app and re-added it.

I've restarted my mac several times.

I have been able to build this previously and had no permissions issues. Does anyone have any ideas about why Xcode suddenly doesn't have enough permissions to `"Copy Swift standard libraries into App.app"`?

Answer (score 1):

Well I finally figured this out after days of going around in circles.

I was convinced I had updated Xcode a while ago to 12.2 and had successfully built since then but I must be wrong.

To fix the issue I had to select "Legacy Build System" on the Workspace settings on Xcode to successfully build the app.

For anyone else using Ionic and Capacitor, if you upgrade to Xcode 12.2 you might have to also do this. If you don't and can figure out how to build with the new system please let me know as the Legacy Build System will eventually get deprecated, putting me back to square one.

At least I have a workaround for now!